# Is there a Wordpress filter that can remove classes on certain menu item?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

[image]

I have two parent menu items where it contains the same sub-item ("*Persian Cats*") pointing on the same page. I want to remove the extra class being added by Wordpress because it creates two active states for the parent items. In the frontend, both "*Cats*" & "*Pets*" are being highlighted indicating they're currently active or there are items under them that is active.

I tried using jQuery to remove it and it works, my only problem with that approach, for a split second it will set both item to 'active' state but once the document is fully loaded, that's just when it removes the extra class. Javascript might not be ideal solution for this. I need to remove the class right before it's written as html.

So I was wondering, if there's a filter or action hooks that I can use to remove the extra class when using **wp_nav_menu()** to call for a menu. This is a default behaviour of Wordpress where when two items that are identically the same (pointing to the same page) are active, it will add extra class of "active or current" to their respective parent as active. What I want to happen, there should be only one active parent even they're present in both parent items.

This question is more of a Wordpress problem than html. I've tried resorting using Javascript to remove that extra class whenever the item is active so that there can only be one parent item that is active. But like what I said, I dismiss that approach because for a split of second, it shows as active and then when some parts of the website loaded, it will remove the  active state.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the wordpress nav php or is this question just about html

Answer (score 1):

WordPress provides the `nav_menu_css_class` filter, that allows addind and removing css classes from each menu item.

I didn't test the following code, but it must help you to find out the solution:

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    static $current_class_already_added = false;
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
        if (!$current_class_already_added) {
            $current_class_already_added = true;
        } else {
            unset($classes[array_search('current-menu-item', $classes)]);
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
```

Hope it helps!